Microsoft Azure DevOps builds include all code and debug
We are trying to automate a 4.72 web site build from Azure DevOps to IIS. In the yaml of the pipeline, we have tried various different parameters, below is the latest.
However, we still get source files and debug symbols pushed to IIS even if this is meant to be a release build. The alternative of publishing from Visual Studio with the "Precompile before publishing" true, and both "emit debug" and "updateable" as false works fine and does not create an app_code directory.
variables:
  solution: '**/mysolution.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:WDPMergeOption=DonotMerge /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:EnableUpdateable=false /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


Hi, please try to add this /p:DebugType=None to the msbuildArgs and see if it works. The DebugType option causes the compiler to generate debugging information and place it in the output file or files. I found this question and this behavior change for your reference.

These are the buildArgs we have now. It is leaving out symbol files. It is compiling library projects dll's in the bin directory but it is putting all the web site source code files onto the IIS which is not what we want of course.
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
/p:WDPMergeOption=DonotMerge
/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
/p:DebugSymbols=false
/p:DebugType=None
/p:EnableUpdateable=false
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"

Hi @user10069751, you can add the /p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="App_Code" to the MSBuild Arguments to exclude "App_Code" folder from the deployment.


However, we still get source files and debug symbols pushed to IIS even if this is meant to be a release build.

Add this /p:DebugType=None to the MSBuild Arguments to stop creating debug symbols.  The DebugType option causes the compiler to generate debugging information and place it in the output file or files.
A partial solution:

Add the /p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="App_Code" to the MSBuild Arguments to exclude "App_Code" folder from the deployment.  Here is the reference.
Add the ExcludeFilesFromDeployment to the MSBuild Arguments to exclude other unrequired files from the deployment.
For example: /p:ExcludeFilesFromDeployment="*.cs;Web.*.config;*.csproj*"


I think excluding the folder is only a partial solution. There are source code files through out all folders such as under our UI/ There are approximately double the number of files on the IIS folder compared to a build that we do from a visual studio publish.
/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
Something is causing this not to precompile even we have this parameter.

Hi @user10069751, thanks for your update. So, the source files are not only in the app_code directory.

The VSBuild@1 task is used to build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property.  To troubleshoot this, can you please copy the actual msbuild command from the VSBuild@1 task log and manually run the command to build and deploy IIS in your local? You can find Developer Command Prompt in the Visual Studio menu Tools > command line > Developer Command Prompt. This way, we can know if the issue is related to the pipeline task or the msbuild command itself.

Hi @user10069751,  I tested the command you are using in my side; it will create a zip in the $(build.artifactStagingDirectory), the app_code folder is not in the zip after I added the argument /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true. Can you please double check the files in the $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)? The vsBuild task in your question is used to build and package web applications. It prepares everything needed for deployment but does not actually deploy the package to IIS. Could you please share your complete yaml or your deployment steps?
